# How to Handle Optional cases in MyPy Type Checking of Python Code

Tags: python, pandas, types, static-analysis, mypy

I am trying my hand at Python 3 type hinting in order to make my code cleaner. Whenever I try to pass my code via mypy, there are some repeated errors mentioning something about Optional data types, and I cannot figure out why.

Here is a sample function.

```
def directory_to_dataframe(directory_name: str) -> pandas.DataFrame:
    '''
    Get the contents of a directory as a single dataframe.

    :param directory_name: The directory to read
    '''
    # print(directory_name)
    directory: str = os.path.join(CONTAINER_ROOT, directory_name)

    def read_method(parquet: str) -> pandas.DataFrame:
        return pandas.read_parquet(path=os.path.join(directory,
                                                     parquet))

    if not os.path.isdir(s=directory):
        return pandas.DataFrame()
    files_to_read: Iterator[str] = filter(
        lambda filename: filename.endswith('.parquet'),
        os.listdir(path=directory))
    try:
        return pandas.concat(objs=map(read_method, files_to_read),
                             verify_integrity=True,
                             ignore_index=True).fillna(value=0)  # Mypy raises error
    except ValueError:
        return pandas.DataFrame()
```

Mypy complains that `Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[DataFrame]", expected "DataFrame")`

I thought `pandas.concat()` will always return a dataframe, so I fail to see why the return type has to be Optional (which implies a possibility of `None` return).

Here is another similar case.

```
daily_count: pandas.DataFrame = pandas.DataFrame(data=daily_ids['ID'].value_counts()).reset_index()
```

Mypy complains `expression has type "Optional[DataFrame]", variable has type "DataFrame"`

So I am missing something about when to apply `Optional` to variable or function return types to make mypy happy. Also, if I do apply `Optional`, then in any further operation involving the variable, MyPy complains the operation is not valid on `None` type.

Comment: Oof. I think because a lot of pandas methods use the whole `inplace=True` pattern, where potentially they might return `None`. Since you know it doesn't, you could use `cast`

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you using? What stubs are you using for pandas?

Comment: I am using pandas 1.0.5, not sure how to find the stub version. concat does not have an inplace argument. Also whichever method has it, usually defaults it to False so that I get a modified copy. Does it mean I have to give the default value to make mypy happy? When I need inplace modification, can mypy adjust its expectation according to the parameter? Also, how to use cast in this instance?

Comment: It's not `pd.concat`, it's `.fillna(value=0)`. The type system has no knowledge of what effect arguments can have on the return value. Again, though, you *can* just use `typing.cast`